# can't edit the preference of Hyper Terminal

Tags: terminal, preferences, hyper

I'm starting with Hyper terminal and want to edit the preferences.
-when I click edit, then preferences, the notepad opens with the settings, it stays open for a few seconds then it closes automatically. I cannot edit/select/delete the text in it at all.
any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the config file for **Hyper.js** is located at

```
C:\Users\{userName}\AppData\Roaming\Hyper\.hyper.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @shailesh said. You can also ensure to check your system's notepad application, if it needs to be updated please do update. cos your hyper solely depends on it, You can update, or uninstall and reinstall your notepad, if it doesn't work, then go

`C:\Users\{userName}\AppData\Roaming\Hyper\.hyper.js`

That should get it fixed, and you should be able to open your preferences even afterwards.